# Processing Methods using three stings

Tags: java

Write a Processing method to return one of three strings, depending on the value of the parameter x. If x is even, the method should return “Even”. If x is divisible by three, the method should return “By three”. If x is neither even nor divisible by three, the method should return “Just odd”.
The signature for your method should be String evenOdd(int x)

Comment: what have u tried so far ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember to provide a minimal and complete example of the problem at hand. See more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've tried using to import javax.swing.*; by using the string oddEven(int x) { if (x%2==0){ ; return "even"; if (x%3 == 3) { return "JUST ODD" ;

Comment: Add the code to your question instead so it's easier to read. AND you're supposed to ask a question, not just throw in a request for us to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
String evenOdd(int x)
{
    if (x%2 == 0) //number is even when it is divisible by 2
        return "Even";
    else if(x%3 == 0) //if remainder is 0 then it is divisible by three
        return "By three";
    else
        return "Just Odd";
}
```

Comment: Don't do homework for them. They are learning and we are here to help them learn.

Comment: @MichaelBruesch I saw her comment first and and she got it almost right except for the (x%3 == 3) part.

Comment: My apologies. I missed her comment. Carry on. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code, which you have left in the comments, is that they are asking for the number to be divisible by three, meaning a remainder of 0. Your code is trying to find a remainder of 3.

so, rather than writing `if (x % 3 == 3)`, say `if (x % 3 == 0)`.

Basically your full code would look as follows:

```
string evenOdd(int x)
{
    string theResponse = "";
    if (x % 2 == 0) // if x is divisible by 2 with no remainders
    {
        theResponse = "Even!";
    }

    else if (x % 3 == 0) // if x is divisible by 3 with no remainders
    {
        theResponse = "By three!";
    }

    else
    {
        theResponse = "Odd";
    }

    return theResponse;
}
```